# How to verify if a graphical model has the markov property?

Tags: markov-process, recurrent-neural-network, hidden-markov-model

If I draw the computational graph of an HMM and an RNN from an architectural point of view they look very similar. The main difference is that an RNN gets some input $x$ and the HMM only operates on the latent sequence. From my understanding - and reading that from the drawn graph - both the hidden states $h_i$ in the RNN and the latent variable $Z_i$ are conditionally dependent on the previous state and produce some output. What I don't understand is, that an HMM is said to have the markov property (i.e., is memoryless) whereas the RNN does not. Why, where can I observe the difference? How can I read that property from a computational graph (if at all)?

Answer (score 1):

The Markov property applies to sequences of random variables. Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ be a sequence of random variables, it is said to follow the Markov property iif:
$$
p(x_n|x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})=p(x_n|x_{n-1}).
$$

Thus, if you can show, from the computational graph or any other equations defining your model, that the distribution of $X_n$ given $X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}$ only depends on $X_{n-1}$ you have proven the Markov property for the sequence of r.v. in question. The Markov property for the hidden random variables in a HMM is indeed one of the core definitions of HMMs.

RNNs -in the simplest models- have indeed architectures which seem to exhibit a Markovian property. I think however that this term is not really used because hidden variables in RNN are not random variables. Hence there might be a problem of definition; even though it is true that the dependency on the past states is reduced to the depency on the last state (at least in the most simple RNNs).

As a final remark, if you generalize RNNs with stochastic hidden random variables (you can see the deterministic case as a particular case) then you will be able to treat it as some kind of HMM and properly show the Markovian property (or not). See for example : [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eepxing/Class/10708-17/project-reports/project10.pdf) or [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03237172/document).